# What is used to power the Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: pi-4, usb, power-supply

Just got a Raspberry Pi 4B, 4 GB, (first time), and have been having fun trying to figure out what it takes for power. According to the extension kit I got, [Raphael Ultimate Kit for Raspberry Pi](https://docs.sunfounder.com/projects/raphael-kit/en/latest/install_setup_os/what_do_we_need.html), it wants a USB-C for power. According to the [Raspberry Pi Website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-getting-started/2), it wants a micro USB for power. Which one is correct?

While writing the Q, [This website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/1#) also said USB-C.

Comment: which connector does your RPi have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Raspberry Pi website"](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-getting-started/2) you referenced is not actually "The Raspberry Pi website" any longer. It's a long, complex and pretty boring story, but in a nutshell:

- RaspberryPi.**org** was formed as an offshoot of the "Charity Foundation"
- The "Charity Foundation" found great commercial success, and was "spun off" into a for-profit business
- RaspberryPi.**com** was formed as an offshoot of the "For Profit Business", and now handles all sales, distribution and support of RPi.

IOW, the **".org*** website isn't maintained by the people who are now making money - thus it "lags behind".

WRT the [Raphael Ultimate Kit for Raspberry Pi](https://docs.sunfounder.com/projects/raphael-kit/en/latest/install_setup_os/what_do_we_need.html): I saw nothing on that website stating they were an **Authorized Reseller** for Raspberry Pi. Not saying they aren't; just saying I didn't see any evidence to that effect in a quick look. I would advise caution; there are lots of authorized resellers, and AFAIK, they are all obligated to sell at the price point dictated by RaspberryPi.com.

##### All of that said: If you have a genuine RPi 4B, it uses a USB-C connector.

Comment: The Raphael Kit didn’t have a Pi in it, it just had the diagram on the website. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your kit didn't come with documentation (or a power supply) I suggest you get https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/available-now-the-official-raspberry-pi-beginners-guide-5th-edition/ and read it (before plugging in).

The earlier edition (for Pi4) is available for download https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/books/beginners-guide-4th-ed/pdf

The power connection should be obvious from comparing to your board.